# Apply Aspect Oriented Programming to Web Service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, aop

I’m looking for a way to apply the AOP concept to a web service. It is pretty easy to do this for creating a plain class.

Example MyClass

Normally you can create a new instance of a class this way

```
MyClass NewClass =  new MyClass();
```

To create an instance of this class with an aspect around it using AOP, you normally have a library that you specify the class type and the aspect you want to apply.

Example MyClass

```
MyClass NewClass = MyProxyClassManager.CreateNewAOPClass(typeof(MyClass));
```

However this proves to be challenging when attempting to this for the class attached to your Web Service.
I need a way that instead of returning the normal class attached to the web service I can return a proxy class based on the web service class.

BTW: I am applying AOP using the castle project.
http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your complete technology stack but with WebAPI you can create custom `DelegatingHandler`'s to wrap around service calls. See [the official website](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/http-message-handlers) for more details

example handler:

```
public class MessageHandler1 : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Process request");
        // Call the inner handler.
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        Debug.WriteLine("Process response");
        return response;
    }
}
```

handler registration

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new MessageHandler1());
        // Other code not shown...
    }
}
```